# How to get postgressql database native datatypes in rails server console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, types, native

I having a rails application, with database as postgressql.

I am having a requirement, where i need to share the datatype of the field as per postgres sql database terminology for the sake of API integration.

Is there any way or method by which we can get the native data types of PostgreSQL database of my application.

i tried the below commands in rails console

```
fields_array ["abc","cde","mno","pqr","stv" ,,,,,,, so on]

fields_array.each do |field_name|
 p field_type = User.type_for_attribute(field_name).type
 p sql_type = User.type_for_attribute(field_name).sql_type ## not working###
end
```

But i am getting the datatype as per rails. i need the datatype of the column and size as per the postgressql native datatype. as there are hundredes of fields, i want to loop through them, and get the datatype of each field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sql_type = User.columns.map{ |column| column.sql_type if c.name == field_name }.compact.first
```

You can get all the column `sql_types` in the `User.columns` collection. You iterate with map over them and return the `column.sql_type` if its name is equal to the field_name. This returns an array with many `nil`s and one `sql_type` string if the field_name exists. `.compact` then just clears the array from `nil`s and returns a single element array. Now you can call `.first` to get the plain string.